# How to render sub-templates based on the current template data?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm making a web application where users can submit a question and anyone can answer it.

I just got the answering (commenting) functionality down, but when you answer one question, the answer appears on all question templates. How can I get it to only appear on the question they typed it on.

JS Code for answering:

```
Template.question.events({
  'click #submit-answer': function(e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var answer = t.find("#answer-input").value;

    Answers.insert({
      answer: answer,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: Meteor.user(),
      username: Meteor.user().username
    });
  }
});

Template.question.helpers({
  Answers: function() {
    return Answers.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

And my HTML:

```
{{#each Answers}}
  {{> answer}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: How do you determine which question does the answer relate to? You should store the question id somewhere or store the answers as sub-documents in the question entry.

Comment: @MasterAM So in the Questions.insert({}), should I give it an id thing and give it a random number?

Comment: Each question should have an id. It is automatically generated by the server as the question is inserted and synced back to the client. Then, you can use the id (`_id`) when creating the answers.

Comment: @MasterAM Where would I put the `this._id` code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to associate the questions and answers:

```
Template.question.events({
  'click #submit-answer': function(e,t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var answer = t.find("#answer-input").value;

    Answers.insert({
      answer: answer,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: Meteor.userId(),
      username: Meteor.user().username,
      questionId: this._id
    });
  }
});

Template.question.helpers({
  Answers: function() {
    return Answers.find({questionId: this._id}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

Note that I have changed the `owner` to the take in the userId and not the entire `user` object.

The answer has a `questionId` field and it is used in the selector in the `Answers` helpers.

If the answers only makes sense when related to the questions, you can embed them as sub-documents directly in the `question` objects.

Not doing so has the downside that it requires you to create a reactive join, which does not have an efficient and canonical implementation at the moment.

Comment: That worked thank you :) - When I click Answer this question, it always opens up the textbox for the first question, not the one I clicked

Comment: You should edit your code to include more code, or, probably better yet, post it as a new question.

Comment: I'm talking about in my web app, not here. Like, If I click "answer this question" on my app, it opens up the textfield for the question at the top. How can I fix that?

Comment: Of course, but since questions on SO should be specific, it would be better to create a new one.